# I'm old school - cypher

Tags: cipher

> Can you solve this encoded text?:

**4 4673 48 92768 3279 67 267464**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says

> I HOPE IT WASNT EASY OR BORING

Using

> The letters on a [telephone pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad) (T9)

Comment: oh wow. i searched for that kind of solver ... where can i find it?

Comment: @lois6b There's one [here](http://www.dcode.fr/t9-cipher).